How can I change my bank account on my online account at Planetshares (planetshares.uptevia.pro.fr/)?
I tried to go to https://planetshares.uptevia.pro.fr/ but I can't see the option to change the account: the bank account fields are greyed out, even after clicking on the "modify" button.

How can I change my bank account on my online account in my Planethares account (planetshares.uptevia.pro.fr/)?

Have you considered contacting customer support? It's the second time you're asking for product support for some very French-specific products. AFAIK you're the only regular Frenchman here, chances are that if you don't know something about France - you wouldn't get a response here faster than actually contacting the customer service of the company.

@littleadv I'll do so if no replies

It's always a good idea to contact customer service first.

@keshlam why?~~

Because they are presumably somebody knows. Here, there is no guarantee of it. Customer support is part of what you are paying for when you use their product; take advantage of it.

@keshlam true but posting here is faster+help future users.

Update (2024-12-19): their new site (https://www.investors.uptevia.com/investor/#/profil) released in early Dec. 2024 allows users to change their bank accounts online account


Old answer:
This can't be changed online. One must mail (physical mail) the "Formulaire de Mise à jour de coordonnées personnelles - Personnal informations update Form":

Form:

